# Serializable class with coroutines?

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

I have a class, which I want to make `serializable` (to see some public variables in the inspector), but I also need to use `Coroutines` in that class. To use `Coroutines` in my class I must inherit it from MonoBehaviour. But then I can't use features of the `serializable` class.

```
public class Act1HomeAwake : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Act1_1HomeAwake act1_1HomeAwake;

     public void StartAct1(int subActNumber)
     {
         switch(subActNumber)
         {
             case 1: act1_1HomeAwake.StartSubAct1_1(); break;
         }                    
     }
 }

 [System.Serializable]
 public class Act1_1HomeAwake // : MonoBehaviour
 {
     // don't see this 2 variables in the inspector WITH inheriting from MonoBehaviour
     public OpenCloseAnimation openCloseEyesScript;
     public Text textTipsTasksComponent;

     // WITHOUT inheriting from MonoBehaviour compiler don't understand this construction
     StartCoroutine("OpenCloseEyesAnimation");
 }
```

Comment: Your code is not valid C#? you are trying to call a method from outside any class member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize the class you want to display:

```
[Serializable] // this is needed to show the object in Inspector
public class OpenCloseAnimation {}

[Serializable]
public class Act1_1HomeAwake 
{
    public OpenCloseAnimation openCloseEyesScript;
    public void CallCoroutine(MonoBehaviour mb)
    {
         mb.StartCoroutine(OpenCloseEyesAnimation());
    }
    public IEnumerator OpenCloseEyesAnimation(){ yield return null;}
}
```

But think that maybe you are doing it wrong. If you need a coroutine in your class, then maybe it is meant to be a MonoBehaviour. Other way is to start the coroutine from the MonoBehaviour containing your object.

```
public class MbClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Act1_1HomeAwake homeAwake;
    void Start(){
         // Considering you don't pass the MB in ctor anymore.
         this.homeAwake = new Act1_1HomeAwake();
         StartCoroutine(this.homeAwake.OpenCloseEyesAnimation());
    }
}
```